# Newbie Python Regex question: Pulling dates from webpage

Tags: python, regex

I'm looking to use Python to pull a regular string of text from a webpage - the source code runs like this:

```
<br /><strong>Date: 06/12/2010</strong> <br />
```

It always begins

```
<strong>Date:
```

& ends

```
</strong>
```

I've already scraped the text of the webpage and just want to pull the date and similarly structured information. Any suggestions how to do this? (Sorry this is such a newbie question!)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import re

text = "<br /><strong>Date: 06/12/2010</strong> <br />"
m = re.search("<strong>(Date:.*?)</strong>", text)
print m.group(1)
```

Output

```
Date: 06/12/2010
```

Comment: Yet another one gets bitten by greediness... this will give you a really large group spanning everything from the first `<Strong>Data:` to the last `</strong>`.

Comment: @nmichaels. I just did while you were commenting. :)

Comment: Thanks hugely - that worked for me. Now trying to work out what the `.group(1)` bit actually means so I can assign the results to a dictionary. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

You can use a regular expression:

```
import re
pattern = re.compile(r'<strong>Date:(?P<date>.*?)</strong>') # re.MULTILINE?
# Then use it with
pattern.findall(text) # Returns all matches
# or
match = pattern.search(text) # grabs the first match
match.groupdict() # gives a dictionary with key 'date'
# or
match.groups()[0] # gives you just the text of the match.
```

or try to parse the thing with [beautiful soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/).

[This](http://www.pythonregex.com/) is a good place to test out your Python regexes.

Comment: It gives the group a name (date.)  It's not strictly necessary; you could leave out `?P<date>`, but then `match.groupdict()` wouldn't work.  Look for `?P<` on http://docs.python.org/library/re.html